# Fonts work on hosting generated domain but not custom domain

Tags: css, dns, font-face, pagoda-box

I have a site hosted on Pagodabox. They gave my site a domain of whitevanboys.gopagoda.com but I have added my own DNS records to use a custom domain of "whitevanboys.co.uk".

That's all working fine but I've found that my custom @font-face fonts are only working when I go to whitevanboys.gopagoda.com and not the whitevanboys.co.uk domain.

This issue is happening on Firefox and Chrome but not Safari.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. The database was still referencing whitevanboys.gopagoda.com as the site domain. I've changed this to the whitevanboys.co.uk domain now and it works fine.
If anyone would like to explain why this has fixed the issue I'd appreciate that!
B